# How do I join the thread to stop it?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.adprogress_progressBar);


    final Thread timerThread = new Thread() {

        private volatile boolean running = true;
        public void terminate() {
            running = false;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(running) {
            mbActive = true;
                try {
                int waited = 0;
                    while(mbActive && (waited < TIMER_RUNTIME)) {
                    sleep(200);
                        if(mbActive) {
                            waited += 200;
                            updateProgress(waited);
                        }
                    }
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                running=false;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    timerThread.start();
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    if (location != null) {

        TextView text;
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t2);
        String str= "Latitude is " + location.getLatitude() + "\nLongitude is " + location.getLongitude();

        text.setText(str);
        text.postInvalidate();
    }

}
```

How would I stop the thread in onCreate from onLocationChanged? I need to stop the progressbar once the GPS provides the coordinates. I need to join the threads using join(). Solution will be helpful.

Comment: How about a inner class extending Thread? This way you can have access to this "terminate" method without need to join the Thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply declare in your Activity a member :

```
private Thread mTimerThread = null;
```

then in your onCreate() replace :

```
final Thread timerThread = new Thread() {
```

with

```
mTimerThread = new Thread() {
```

and in onLocationChanged :

```
if (mTimerThread != null && mTimerThread.isAlive()) {
    mTimerThread.terminate();
}
```

to achieve what you want.

However, as others mentioned, I would also recommend using custom `AsyncTask` as it would be most clear way of threading in your case.

Comment: Can you help me on how to implement the background process using AsyncTask here?

Comment: @Suva well yes, I could, but I am not always here. I suggest you really implement some [tutorial example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask3) first and then it would be much more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Make timerThread a class member and not a locale variable, in this way you should access it from the onLocationChanged method

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask instead, store the Future and stop the thread yourself.

Comment: No need to store the Future. Just make the AsyncTask implement LocationListener, so it would know when to return from doInBackground()

Answer (score 0):

If this is not a home work assignment, then I see no need to `join()`. Even more so when you're trying to join the UI thread with an arbitrary thread, effectively casuing an [ANR](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html).

Either:

1. Create you own class extending `Thread`, implement your `terminate()` method, and then call it whenever you want.
2. Create your own class extending [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), implementing LocationListener, and use its [onProgressUpdate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) method.

Comment: Can you help me on how to implement the background process using AsyncTask here?

Comment: What problems did you encounter?